# R - Using System.time to get current date, and change time to fixed values for timevis timeline

Tags: r, vis.js-timeline

I am attempting to use the timevis package to create an interactive single day timeline builder. Each item that goes onto the timeline will have a "length" attribute in minutes.

I am limiting the timeline to todays date between 8AM and 5PM.

I want each item to start off at 8AM, but the end date needs to be

```
todayAM + length
```

I can alter how the lengths are stored if needed.

Any ideas on how to manipulate the times so that I can get the basic blocks plotted. (The user will then drag them to desired places on the timeline.)

```
library(timevis)

today <- as.character(Sys.Date())
todayAM <- paste(today,"08:00:00")
todayPM <- paste(today, "17:00:00")

items <- data.frame(
  category = c("Room","IceBreaker","Activity","Break"),
  categoryid=c(1,2,3,4),
  name = c("Big Room","Introductions","Red Rover","Lunch"),
  length = c(480,60,120,90)
)


data <- data.frame(
  id = 1:4,
  start = c(todayAM, todayAM, todayAM, todayAM),
  end = c(todayPM, todayPM, todayPM, todayPM),
  content = items$name,
  group = items$categoryid
)

groups <- data.frame(id= items$categoryid, content = items$category)

timevis(
  data = data,
  groups = groups,
  fit = TRUE,
  options = list(editable = TRUE, multiselect = TRUE, align = "center", stack = TRUE,
                 start = todayAM,
                 end = todayPM
                 )
  
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this :

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
starthour <- 8
data <- items %>% mutate(start = as.POSIXct(Sys.Date()) + hours(starthour) + minutes(lag(cumsum(items$length),1,default=0)),
                         end   = as.POSIXct(Sys.Date()) + hours(starthour) + minutes(cumsum(items$length)),
                         content = name)

timevis::timevis(
  data = data,
  fit = TRUE,
  options = list(editable = TRUE, multiselect = TRUE, align = "center", stack = TRUE)
)
```

[image]
You'll then have to set timezone option according to your needs : `as.POSIXct` create a UTC date.

Comment: Thanks for that!  I really like the cumsum of the times to create the staggered layout. Unfortunately I had to remove it due to the some events needing to overlap. (Mainly the room group which will run the entire day and causes everything to shift by that amount of time.)